# How can I get the value or ID of an object dragged using Draggable JS

Tags: javascript, draggable

If I have something like this code using Shopify's Draggable library:

```
droppable.on('droppable:dropped', (evt) => {
  if (droppableOrigin == evt.dropzone.dataset.dropzone) {
    //if dropped into wrong container then: 
    checkWord();
  }
});
```

How can I get the value or ID or innerHTML of the dragged item to pass into checkWord? I'm not an expert in JavaScript, so maybe this is a JavaScript problem and not a Draggable problem.

For context, my draggable items look like this:

```
<div class="dropzone occupied" data-dropzone="1" id="word" value="ma"> 
    <div class="draggable" id="word">ma</div>
</div>
```